# What is the impact of CRUD operations and JOINS with multiple indexes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have a table with 120 columns. It has 8 indexes on it (1 clustered, 7 non-clustered). As a test, I inserted 3,400 rows into the table and it took an average of 12 seconds.

I created the same table with a different name and created 32 additional indexes on it (total 40 indexes) and again insert same 3,400 rows it took an average of 13.5 seconds.

I read before when an index is created, a copy of the table is created and sorted by that column that participates in the index.

I have 2 questions:

1) Is it true that for every index a copy of the table is created?

2) 32 indexes add only 1.5 seconds for the same `INSERT` command. Does this average remain for 10,000 rows? or for 80 indexes?

---

I have another question:

3)<strike>when we have a Foreign key on a column SQL Server automatically create non-cluster index on it</strike>.When we have a forein key on a column If we create a non-cluster index on it,is this Index useful for quering or Joins?

Comment: Why does your table have 120 fields? What fields do the indexes cover? Duration of insert statements are relative so 12 seconds doesn't mean much without other hardware specifications and a baseline insert time.

Comment: So long I read in comment and answer `Why some thing has some features`.I have a form that has 120 fields.please say your point of view.thanks

Comment: Just because your UI has 120 fields (your poor users!) doesn't mean you need to have only one table with exactly as many. Regardless my other questions still stand. **What do your indexes look like - how many fields does each cover?**

Comment: It's a test form and users should see all questions and options.first 8 index cover 3 fields and every other 32 index cover 1 column

Comment: I never thought I'd have to say this, but watch out SQL Server 2008 has a limit on the number of indexes per table: 1 Clustered Index + 999 Nonclustered Index = 1000 Index total.  Also, do you realize that you can only search the table using 1 index at a time.

Comment: Reg. Q3 about Joins: Different Join algorithms need different indexes. See http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) op asks: `Is it true that by every index a copy of table created?` it is not true.  an index will store the indexed columns and the pointer back (like the the clustered PK, etc.) to the row.  it will also store any INCLUDE columns, but that is another topic.

2) it is hard to guess on the timings not knowing the hardware, the tables, or the indexes in question.  I'm sure that SQL Server is good at optimizing the maintenance of indexes.  You should test this by inserting the same rows with only a PK and then try again with 40 indexes and then again with 80.  I'm sure the bulk of the time is just the inserts.

**EDIT**

3) op asks `when we have a Foreign key on a column SQL Server automatically create non-cluster index on it.this Index useful for quering or Joins?`  SQL Server does NOT automatically create an index for foreign keys.  However, adding an index on FK columns may be useful.  If you write a query that joins two tables on the FK, then the index MAY be used. Consider the following:

```
tableA
RowID    int PK
RowDate  datetime
OtherID  int

tableB
OtherID  int PK
someValue varchar(5)
```

if you add a FK for tableA.OtherID to tbaleB.OtherID  and use this query:

```
select * from tableA a INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.OtherID=b.OtherID
WHERE a.RowDate<'2011/1/1'
```

then an index on tableA.OtherID won't be used, an index on tableA.RowDate will be used and the PK index on tableB.OtherID will be used.

```
select * from tableA a INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.OtherID=b.OtherID 
WHERE b.someValue='AA'

could also be written as:

select * from tableb b INNER JOIN tableA b ON b.OtherID=a.OtherID 
WHERE b.someValue='AA'
```

then an index on tableA.OtherID may be used, and any index on tableb.someValue will be used.

Comment: thank you for your answer that is useful.please see my edit and Question 3.

Comment: Dear @KM:I create a test table in my database in join it with main table on column that has not any index and in execution plan I got missing index message that suggest index on column in main table.What is your idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say.  1) You created a test table.  2) you wrote a query that joins that test table to the table in the original question. 3) there is no index on the join column in the original question table. 4) execution plan indicated there is a missing index. 5) not sure what the question is?

Comment: my comment is about Question 3.I have main table that has 8 index on it.when I create a test table and join it to main table on column that has not index in execution plan I get missing index message and when I create an index on it the cost will be 4%

Comment: what was the cost before the index?

Comment: for my test I creat two copy of my table.one with 8 index one with 40 index.for 8 index the cost is 96% and for 40 index the cost is 4%

Comment: `one with 8 index one with 40 index`, you can only use one index per table at at time, if one of the 32 additional indexes was used in the second test, then it would account for the cost going down.

Comment: Sorry I don't know why SOF does not allow to edit comment after specific time.I mean one table with 8 index and one table with 40 index.and you are right that just one index will use in a time

Answer (score 2):

*1 ) Is it true that for every index a copy of the table is created?*

No. Every index will create a data structure such as a btree or hash table with pointers to your table. one pointer per row. they are fairly inexpensive in terms of disk space.

*2 ) 32 indexes add only 1 .5 seconds for the same INSERT command. Does this
average remain for 10, 000 rows? or for 80 indexes?*

you will have to benchmark it to know for sure, but most likely, yes. indexes typically scale in a lineary fashion.

Comment: *"they are fairly inexpensive in terms of disk space."* Not sure I agree, as it really depends - it's like saying "*cars are fairly inexpensive in terms of money."* Sure, if you stick to the used lot behind the Kia dealership, but it's quite tempting to venture elsewhere... especially with things like DTA prompting you to add umpteen indexes (with 20 include columns) to satisfy a handful of occasional queries.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is it true that for every index a copy of the table is created?

Partially. The columns that are indexed by a particular (non-clustered) index will be "copied" into index data structure (typically a B-Tree), but the rest of the columns will not. BTW, some RDMBSes support a form of index compression (such as Oracle, not sure about MS SQL Server), which may significantly "shrink" a footprint of a low-selectivity index.

As for a clustered index, the table and the index are actually the same data structure. So if all you have is a single index (i.e. just a primary key), making it clustered will typically lower the space required compared to a classical B-Tree / table heap combination that you get from a non-clustered index.

**However**, clustered index increases "copying" that is going on for **all other** (i.e. non-clustered) indexes. From MSDN:

*"The key values from the clustered index are used by all non-clustered indexes as lookup keys and therefore are stored in each nonclustered index leaf entry."*

If you cannot escape having many indexes, at least get rid of the cluster and use only non-clustered indexes.

> 2) 32 indexes add only 1.5 seconds for the same INSERT command. Does this average remain for 10,000 rows? or for 80 indexes?

With only 3,400 rows (or 10,000 for that matter), I suspect you are still well within the confines of the cache, which may mask the performance problem you'll probably have maintaining all these indexes for a larger data set. As always, you won't know for sure until you actually benchmark with representative amounts of data...

### --- EDIT ---

> 3)when we have a Foreign key on a column SQL Server automatically create non-cluster index on it.this Index useful for quering or Joins?

It may or may not increase the performance, depending on how particular query is constructed. It may also be significant for cascading referential integrity (ON DELETE/UPDATE CASCADE).

If you can live without this index, removing it will increase the performance of modifications, as with removing any other index.

Comment: thanks.I create a test table in my database in join it with main table on column that has not any index and in execution plan I got missing index message that suggest index on column in main table.What is your idea?

Comment: @Nima When JOIN is implemented as a NESTED LOOP, the "outer" table is driving the "inner" table and the inner table better have an index if you care about performance. When **both** parent PRIMARY KEY and child FOREIGH KEY have indexes, the optimizer will typically choose whatever table is more "selective" (i.e. returns fewer rows) as "outer" and the other table then automatically becomes "inner". If you have **only** parent PRIMARY KEY index, then you are making it very expensive for child table to become "inner" and thus limiting optimizer's choices (which may or may not be a problem).